# how to get "start" item value using C# linq query?

Tags: c#, json, list, json.net

```
[{"service":"xxx",
    "processes":
    [
        {
            "name":"tomcat",
            "command":{
                "start": "/server/tomcat01/bin/tomcat01.sh start",
                "stop": "/server/tomcat01/bin/tomcat01.sh stop",
                "restart": "/server/tomcat01/bin/tomcat01.sh restart",
            }       
        }
    ]
}]
```

how to get start item value with using c# linq?

Answer (score 5):

Given the following concrete classes:

```
public class Command
{
    public string start { get; set; }
    public string stop { get; set; }
    public string restart { get; set; }
}

public class Process
{
    public string name { get; set; }
    public Command command { get; set; }
}

public class Services
{
    public string service { get; set; }
    public List<Process> processes { get; set; }
}
```

You can deserialize the json and retrieve a list of all starts with the following:

```
var json = @"[{""service"":""xxx"", ""processes"": [{""name"":""tomcat"", ""command"":{""start"":""/server/tomcat01/bin/tomcat01.shstart"", ""stop"":""/server/tomcat01/bin/tomcat01.shstop"", ""restart"":""/server/tomcat01/bin/tomcat01.shrestart"", } } ] }]";
var deserialized = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Services>>(json);
var starts = deserialized.Select(x => x.processes.Select(p => p.command?.start));
```

Answer (score 3):

Using the Json.Net [LINQ-to-JSON](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/LINQtoJSON.htm) API you could do this:

```
string command = JToken.Parse(json)
    .SelectMany(jo => jo.SelectToken("processes"))
    .Select(jo => (string)jo.SelectToken("command.start"))
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

...which would return `/server/tomcat01/bin/tomcat01.sh start` given your JSON input.

Fiddle: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Ft3q2C

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you want to deserialize your json string into `C# class`.

```
JavaScriptSerializer jss= new JavaScriptSerializer();
CustomClass tempClass = jss.Deserialize<CustomClass>(jsonString);
```

`jsonString` is `json` data which you mentioned in your question. You can then use linq over your class.